# Make a register form and connect to database and then Login and show details

Tags: php

I have a code for `register.php` but it's showing data not added to database.
I am sending every page and code.

config.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "123456";
$db = "mysqladmin";
// This part sets up the connection to the
// database (so you don't need to reopen the connection
// again on the same page).
$ms = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if (!$ms)
{
    echo "Error connecting to database.\n";
}
// Then you need to make sure the database you want
// is selected.
mysqli_select_db($db);
?>
```

Now when I fill up the form it's not adding the details to database and printing the error message.

register.php:

```
<?php
// dbConfig.php is a file that contains your
// database connection information. This
// tutorial assumes a connection is made from
// this existing file.
include ("dbConfig.php");
//Input vaildation and the dbase code
if ($_GET["op"] == "reg")
{
    $bInputFlag = false;
    foreach ($_POST as $field)
    {
        if ($field == "")
        {
            $bInputFlag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $bInputFlag = true;
        }
    }
    // If we had problems with the input, exit with error
    if ($bInputFlag == false)
    {
        die( "Problem with your registration info. "
            ."Please go back and try again.");
    }
    // Fields are clear, add user to database
    // Setup query
    $q = "INSERT INTO dbUsers (`username`,`password`,`email`) " ."VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', " ."PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'), " ."'".$_POST["email"]."')";
    // Run query
    $r = mysqli_query($q);
    // Make sure query inserted user successfully
    if (!mysqli_insert_id())
    {
        die("Error: User not added to database.");
    }
    else
    {
    // Redirect to thank you page.
    Header("Location: register.php?op=thanks");
    }
} // end if
//The thank you page
elseif ( $_GET["op"] == "thanks" )
{
    echo "<h2>Thanks for registering!</h2>";
}
//The web form for input ability
else
{
    echo "<form action=\"?op=reg\" method=\"POST\">\n";
    echo "Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" MAXLENGTH=\"16\">\n";
    echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" MAXLENGTH=\"16\">\n";
    echo "Email Address: <input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" MAXLENGTH=\"25\">\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\">\n";
    echo "</form>\n";
}
// EOF
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
// dBase file
include "dbConfig.php";
if ($_GET["op"] == "login")
{
    if (!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
    {
        die("You need to provide a username and password.");
    }
    // Create query
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `dbUsers` "
        ."WHERE `username`='".$_POST["username"]."' "
        ."AND `password`=PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."') "
        ."LIMIT 1";
    // Run query
    $r = mysqli_query($q);
    if ($obj = @mysqli_fetch_object($r))
    {
        // Login good, create session variables
        $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id;
        $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"];
        $_SESSION["valid_time"] = time();
        // Redirect to member page
        Header("Location: members.php");
    }
    else
    {
        // Login not successful
        die("Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information.");
    }
}
else
{
    //If all went right the Web form appears and users can log in
    echo "<form action=\"?op=login\" method=\"POST\">";
    echo "Username: <input name=\"username\" size=\"15\">";
    echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"8\">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

members.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["valid_user"])
{
    // User not logged in, redirect to login page
    Header("Location: login.php");
}
// Member only content
// ...
// ...
// ...
// Display Member information
echo "<p>User ID: " . $_SESSION["valid_id"];
echo "<p>Username: " . $_SESSION["valid_user"];
echo "<p>Logged in: " . date("m/d/Y", $_SESSION["valid_time"]);
// Display logout link
echo "<p><a href=\"logout.php\">Click here to logout!</a></p>";
?>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
// Logged out, return home.
Header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: please specify what error message you are getting

Comment: Error: User not added to database.

Comment: Please properly indent your code to make it readable. That will not only help us follow the flow of the code but it will also help you debug it. Also, remove the back ticks in the start and end of your code blocks. That will enable some syntax highlighting here on SO.

Comment: Is connection properly established?
You hope you had checked with `mysqli_connect_error();`

Comment: change `die("Error: User not added to database.");` to `die(mysqli_error($ms));` and provide the actual error message

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You shouldn't use mysqls built in `password()` for hashing user passwords. It's very insecure (unsalted sha1-hashes). Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: i have done this:-

change die("Error: User not added to database."); to die(mysqli_error($ms)); and provide the actual error message

Comment: still not working

Comment: yes it will still not work since we're still looking for the actual error. please provide the error message generated

Comment: its just printing a blank page.

and in url its calling this page-- register.php?op=reg

Comment: **Note:** You are currently debugging code that has _serious security issues_ and  _needs to be refactored_. I would recommend rewriting this application _before_ continue debugging it. You store users information. Respect their privacy by _keeping their data safe_.

Comment: i am not doing it in live sir, i am a fresher and doing to understand php and mysql, now how will you teach a fresher?

Comment: @ARITRAPUTATUNDA For learning PHP go to https://www.w3schools.com/php/. this platform is not for training freshers.

Comment: ya i know from there only i studied but i am stuck with this code now.

Comment: @ARITRAPUTATUNDA When you use a query() function you have to add error checks to see if there were any errors while sending the query. Please edit your question and source code to include the error handling code and the error message you get from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using this script from wikihow https://github.com/peredurabefrog/phpSecureLogin/.
you can follow the tutorial and DIY : https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL